# concatenating strings and variables

Tags: java, jsp

i have problems  while concatenating strings and variables. I tried to add quotes and slashes, i tried to move them back and forth, but i wasnt able to find a solution.

I have a class that 'write' a div. I wrote this

```
String var = "width:100px";
String div ="<div class=\"divClass\" style="+var+">";
```

The code i wrote give me

```
   <div class="divClass" style=width:100px>
```

But, in order to write a good code i would need this

```
   <div class="divClass" style="width:100px">
```

with the value of style between quote "".

Comment: Escape or just use single quotes like `"<div class='divClass' style="+var+">"`.

Comment: I would have to question 'WHY' you generate an entire HTML `<div>` in JAVA.

Comment: You've got good answers here but I would also suggest you use a StringBuffer to do your concatenation : they are far more efficient than the concatenation of Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this.

```
String var = "width:100px";
String div ="<div class=\"divClass\" style=\""+var+"\">";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `"` symbol

```
String var = "\"width:100px\"";
String div ="<div class=\"divClass\" style="+var+">";
```

Then div would be

```
<div class="divClass" style="width:100px">
```

The reason we need to do this is that we need to tell the compiler that the quotes symbol `"` is a part of the String and we are not closing the `String` literal yet.

Example

```
System.out.println("hello"); => hello
System.out.println("\"hello\""); => "hello"
```

When the compiler sees `\"` it reads `\` and knows that it has to ignore the next character ie `"`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
String var = "\"width:100px\"";
```

as you will need to escape your quotes